# Validating email in Java

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a registration form which has name, email and password. A confirmation link is sent to user's email address on registering. But before sending links I need to validate email address. I used:

```
public static boolean verifyEmailAddress(String regEmail) {
    boolean result = true;
    try {
        InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(regEmail);
        emailAddr.validate();
    } catch (AddressException ex) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Any of the email it shows valid, example `yutr6767868@huymail.com`, `k999////@sdmail.com`

The email I am getting from `request.getParameter` and storing it in `regEmail`.

What exactly i need to do to make it work ?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: If this is simply asking how to validate email addresses it's a duplicate of many other questions on SO.

Comment: And what's with the jsp tag? There is no mention of jsp or jstl in the questions or answers.

Comment: Be careful if you are using the validate method on InternetAddress class, it clearly states in API method's description that "The current implementation checks many, but not all, syntax rules". It leads to accept for instance this address: user@example as a valid one -altough i am not sure if this is an error according to RFC 822-

Comment: I think most of these questions aren't very well formed, despite some prevalent opinions to the contrary. This person (many years ago now) is using a specific approach w/ Java EE or Jakarta classes. First note: I looked at the source of jakarta.mail v2.0.0 and found calling validate() is the same as passing isStrict=true:Boolean as the 2nd constructor parameter. This validation does seem to allow some permissive strings like `user@host` and also supports multiple addresses, so check: isGroup() too. Second note: the answer to use Apache Commons seems better than any specific regex IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

OK heres about 3 examples
http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-email-address-with-regular-expression/

I think the one you need is

```
package com.mkyong.regex;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class EmailValidator{

  private Pattern pattern;
  private Matcher matcher;

  private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = 
               "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@
               [A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

  public EmailValidator(){
      pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
  }

  /**
   * Validate hex with regular expression
   * @param hex hex for validation
   * @return true valid hex, false invalid hex
   */
  public boolean validate(final String hex){

      matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
      return matcher.matches();

  }
```

}

Whole combination is means, email address must start with “_A-Za-z0-9-” , optional follow by “.[_A-Za-z0-9-]“, and end with a “@” symbol. The email’s domain name must start with “A-Za-z0-9″, follow by first level Tld (.com, .net) “.[A-Za-z0-9]” and optional follow by a second level Tld (.com.au, .com.my) “\.[A-Za-z]{2,}”, where second level Tld must start with a dot “.” and length must equal or more than 2 characters.

Example

```
package com.mkyong.regex;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class EmailValidator{

  private Pattern pattern;
  private Matcher matcher;

  private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = 
               "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@
               [A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

  public EmailValidator(){
      pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
  }

  /**
   * Validate hex with regular expression
   * @param hex hex for validation
   * @return true valid hex, false invalid hex
   */
  public boolean validate(final String hex){

      matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
      return matcher.matches();

  }
```

}

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying

Answer (score 5):

Use [Apache Commons Validator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/). Check the [EmailValidator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html)

You can use it like this example:

```
 EmailValidator validator = EmailValidator.getInstance();
 boolean validEmail = validator.isValid(email);
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of email validators in the public domain.

As mentioned, the [email validator from apache commons](https://github.com/apache/commons-validator/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/validator/EmailValidator.java) is very much in use.

There is a very interesting one [on the apache wicket codebase](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-extensions/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/extensions/validation/validator/RfcCompliantEmailAddressValidator.java), which apparently is quite good as it is a **81** line regular expression. Just for fun, I will copy and paste the whole thing.

```
private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]"
    + ")+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:"
    + "\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:("
    + "?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ "
    + "\\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\0"
    + "31]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\"
    + "](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+"
    + "(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:"
    + "(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z"
    + "|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)"
    + "?[ \\t])*)*\\<(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\"
    + "r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?["
    + " \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)"
    + "?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]"
    + ")*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?["
    + " \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*"
    + ")(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]"
    + ")+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*)"
    + "*:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)?(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+"
    + "|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r"
    + "\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:"
    + "\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t"
    + "]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031"
    + "]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\]("
    + "?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?"
    + ":(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?"
    + ":\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*\\>(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?"
    + ":(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?"
    + "[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)*:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] "
    + "\\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|"
    + "\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>"
    + "@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\""
    + "(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]"
    + ")*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\"
    + "\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?"
    + ":[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\["
    + "\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-"
    + "\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|("
    + "?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)*\\<(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;"
    + ":\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[(["
    + "^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\""
    + ".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\"
    + "]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\"
    + "[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\"
    + "r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] "
    + "\\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]"
    + "|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)?(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\0"
    + "00-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\"
    + ".|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,"
    + ";:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?"
    + ":[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*"
    + "(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\"."
    + "\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:["
    + "^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]"
    + "]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*\\>(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:,\\s*("
    + "?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\"
    + "\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:("
    + "?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=["
    + "\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t"
    + "])*))*@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t"
    + "])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?"
    + ":\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|"
    + "\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*|(?:"
    + "[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\"
    + "]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)*\\<(?:(?:\\r\\n)"
    + "?[ \\t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\""
    + "()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)"
    + "?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>"
    + "@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?["
    + " \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,"
    + ";:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]"
    + ")*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\"
    + "\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)?"
    + "(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\"."
    + "\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:"
    + "\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\["
    + "\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])"
    + "*))*@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])"
    + "+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\"
    + ".(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z"
    + "|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*\\>(?:("
    + "?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*)?;\\s*)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public boolean isEmail(String s) {
    return s.matches("^[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}");
}
```

If you need email to have certain length before the @ character. For instance 5:

```
s.matches("^[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]{5}+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}")
```

The {5} in expression validates length.