# Java - validate email with InternetAddress

Tags: java, validation, email

I got this method:

```
public static boolean isValidEmailAddress(String email) {
       boolean result = true;
       try {
          InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(email);
          emailAddr.validate();
       } catch (AddressException ex) {
          result = false;
       }
       return result;
}
```

but that give me this exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   javax.mail.internet.AddressParser.tokenizeAddress(AddressParser.java:645)
>     at
>   javax.mail.internet.AddressParser.parseAddress(AddressParser.java:113)
>     at
>   javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.(InternetAddress.java:70)
>     at
>   javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.(InternetAddress.java:61)
>     at controller.CtrlUser.isValidEmailAddress(CtrlUser.java:166)   at
>   controller.CtrlSeller.register(CtrlSeller.java:41)    at
>   testController.CtrlSellerUnitTestCase.testRegister(CtrlSellerUnitTestCase.java:41)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229) ....

Comment: are you passing null for email?

Comment: Are you sure that during call to this method, parameter `email` is not null?

Comment: Use this for validation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042329/validating-email-in-java

Comment: thanks to all of you, it was null ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make sure that the email parameter you are passing is not null

Answer (score 5):

It works for me- check to see if you are actually passing a valid string.  It appears you are sending null as your email parameter

Comment: You right it's was this. Something wrong in my unit testing in fact. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
java.net.IDN.toASCII    

public static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    boolean result = true;
    try {
        InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(java.net.IDN.toASCII(email));
        emailAddr.validate();
    } catch (AddressException ex) {
        result = false;
    }
    System.out.println("==> "+result+" : "+email);
    return result;
}
```